# Disable autoscaling in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, layout, accordion, scaling, gsap

I'm working on an AS3 project whereby an element needs to expand (downward) on hover. The problem is that I can't figure out how to expand the element without AS3 auto-scaling all of it's contents.

For example (`this` is a `Sprite`):

```
private function expand(event:Event):void {
  TweenLite.killTweensOf(this);
  TweenLite.to(this, .2, {
    height: _dimensions.tall_height
  });
  return;
}
```

Will automatically grow all children of `this` to fill the available space. I'm looking to disable this functionality, leaving the previously visible content in-place, so that I can reveal additional content with the new space. Playing with `scaleY` in the `TweenLite` statement doesn't seem to do anything.

It doesn't make any sense to me why this is the default behavior, but I come from an HTML (think "box-model") layout mindset, so I think that's getting me into trouble.

Perhaps I've got the wrong idea entirely - is there a more AS3-appropriate method for "expanding" `this` to reveal the extra content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you can't "disable" scaling in Flash. If you want to show only part of an object, you'll have to use what's called a mask.

Suppose you have an object `box` (Sprite), and you want to show only the top 200px of this object:

```
var m:Sprite = new Sprite();

var g:Graphics = m.graphics;
g.beginFill(0);
g.drawRect(0, 0, box.width, 200);
g.endFill();

// Apply mask
box.mask = m;
```

Now later when you want to reveal the entire object, you can simply redraw the mask:

```
var m:Sprite = Sprite(box.mask);

// Redraw mask, now 400px
var g:Graphics = m.graphics;
g.beginFill(0);
g.drawRect(0, 0, box.width, 400);
g.endFill();

// Reapply mask
box.mask = m;
```

And so on.

If you're working with an AS3 project (not Flex), you can pretty much forget about setting width/height.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, this was the perfect start. I also found that (after you add the mask to the display list) you can tween it's height - exactly the effect I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of expanding the Sprite itself, expand its background element(s), which hopefully would have 9 slice scaling enabled.

It also sounds like maybe you're using a mask to hide that additional content. You could consider simply changing the height of the mask.